# PHPStorm 9.0.2 : Cannot find declaration to go

Tags: php, include, editor, phpstorm

I declared a PHP project. I defined 1 ressource root with my include directory. 
When I edit a program, it is not possible to open any include file by using the Ctrl Fonction with the mouse click. The editor indicates "Cannot find declaration to go"

This feature worked in the PHPStotm 8.x version.

Have you any idea about this issue ?

Thanks.

Pascal

Comment: Are you talking about clicking on file names in `include/require` statements? If so -- marking folder as Resource Root does not affect such code as it's for HTML/CSS links/references.

Comment: I already marked folder as Ressource Folde. It worked in PHPStrom 8.x with the same configuration. I dont't unterstand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was because my workspace.xml was corrupted. So, I renamed workspace.xml in oldworkspace.xml and I relaunched PHPStorm. Then, I configured correctly the project and now it works ;)

NB : The workspace.xml is in the .idea folder in the root of your project.